# parsing the highways England xml

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am pretty new with `Python` and I have set myself a little project to parse the `XML` file of the highways *England XML*. My eventual aim is to make a lambda function on `AWS` with the code so that every time something happens to do with the *M25*, I get an alert saying what happened. My problem at the moment is that I don't know how to get it to check for individual words within the XML such as *M25* etc. I can parse it and print out the bigger brackets such as item but that is too broad. here is the code so far:

```
import urllib2
varresponse = urllib2.urlopen('http://m.highwaysengland.co.uk/feeds/rss/AllEvents.xml')

from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse(varresponse)

root = tree.getroot()


for item in root.iter('item'):
        print item.text
```

How to solve such problem?

Answer (score 0):

for that particular case:

```
for item in root.iter('item'):
    road = item.find('road')
    if road is not None and 'M25' in road.text:
        print(item)
```